# JAVA How can I create a List of Strings each referring to a seperate Hashmap<String, Integer>

Tags: java, string, list, generics, hashmap

I am working on a task where I have to build a Language Detector in Java.
Basically what it does, it gets a bunch of data in form of Strings and creates a HashMap for every language. This HashMap saves how often a particular n-gram is listed.

**Previously, I already implemented a simple HashMap Class with following methods:**

- Entry class with key(String) and value()
- add method
- get method
- hashCode
- probe methode

**Here is the constructor for my HashMap Class:**
N = length, basis = 31.

```
public HashMap(int N, int basis) {
            table = (Entry[]) Array.newInstance(Entry[].class.getComponentType(), N);
            this.basis = basis;
}
```

Now I need to implement following method:

```
public void learnLanguage(String language, String text)
```

I would first check if this language is listed in my list1, if not I would add it. Then I would add a HashMap for this specific language, where I store the n-Grams. (From there on its quite simple I think, just need to calculate how often a particular n-Gram is in the String "text" and save it in the HashMap)

But I am struggling with creating the HashMaps.
I attached a image what it should look like..

[how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgxRB.png)

Hope someone can help me out!

What I tried:

Tried creating a HashMap inside a HashMap, but didnt work out:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer>> languageMap;
```

There are some errors and I dont know how to get rid. Also not thinking this is the best option.

Comment: Note: It's a really bad idea to name your class the same as a class from the JDK. It leads to confusion and much wasted time.

Comment: Yes, I know. But it has to be named like this in order to successfully complete the tests.

Comment: You should create like this HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> languageMap;
why there is no key in second hashmap?

Comment: I'm curious... Which educational institution are you attending?

Comment: To be honest, I didn't understand your question. 
Can you give some input, output? 
For example: input: "abcdefghijklmn" output [{"english": ...}, {"other language", ...}], probably like this.I don't see any logical relationship in the picture you provided

Comment: I managed to implement it correcty. I updated the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Soo  Baically what had to be done, was to create a HashMap within a HashMap.

We have a HashMap (table 1) with Strings (languages) as keys and for the values another HashMap (tables 2). So each key i.e. language has a own HashMap where the nGrams are stored and how often they are used in the language.

What I needed to do, was implement a Instance of HashMap which I had created (in order to use my own hash/probe function and other implemented methods).
But Because the name is the same as the HashMap class from the JDK, it let to confusion as @bohemian had pointed out.

The correct initialization for our Table 1 is:

```
LanguageDetector.HashMap<LanguageDetector.HashMap<Integer>> languages;
```

I forgot to mention, that the key in our HashMap is always a String, but the values only can be whatever we initilize it as.

Here is the complete Code for our school task:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class LanguageDetector {

    // n = the length of n-grams to use
    int n;

    // N = the size of the language-specific hash tables ("Tabelle 2")
    int N;

    LanguageDetector.HashMap<LanguageDetector.HashMap<Integer>> languages;
    ArrayList<String> languagesList;
    
    public LanguageDetector(int n, int N) {
        this.n = n;
        this.N = N;
        languages = new LanguageDetector.HashMap<LanguageDetector.HashMap<Integer>>(101, 31);
        languagesList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    //a given String is split into nGrams and for each nGram the most accurate language gets a "point".
    //languaegs and their points are stored in a hash map
    public HashMap<Integer> apply(String text) {
        LanguageDetector.HashMap<Integer> resultMap = new HashMap<>(languagesList.size(), 31);
        ArrayList<String> ngramWinners = new ArrayList<>();
       

        for(String lang : languagesList){
            resultMap.add(lang, 0);  
        }

        int currentCount = 0;
        int maxCount = 0;
        
        //äußere Schleife für ngram-durchlauf 
        int k = n;
        for(int j = 0; j<=text.length()-n; j++){

            //durchlauf aller Sprachen für jedes nGram
            for(int i = 0; i<languagesList.size(); i++){
                
                //bestimmen in welcher Sprache das aktuelle nGram am häufigsten vorkommt
                String ngram = text.substring(j, k);
                currentCount = getCount(ngram, languagesList.get(i));
                //System.out.println(currentCount);
                if(currentCount>maxCount){
                    maxCount = currentCount;
                    //currentCount = 0;
                    ngramWinners.clear();
                    ngramWinners.add(languagesList.get(i));
                    break;
                }
                if(currentCount==maxCount){
                    ngramWinners.add(languagesList.get(i));
                }
            }

            //wenn das nGram in keiner Sprache verwendet wird, gibt es Punkte für niemanden
            if(maxCount != 0){
                //speicherung und aktualisieren des "scores"
                for(int i = 0; i<ngramWinners.size();i++){
                    int newCount = resultMap.get(ngramWinners.get(i)) + 1;
                    resultMap.add(ngramWinners.get(i), newCount);
                    //System.out.println(ngramWinners.get(i));
                }
            }
            ngramWinners.clear();
            maxCount = 0;
            k+=1;
        }

        return resultMap;
    }
    
    public void learnLanguage(String language, String text) {      
        if(languages.get(language) == null){
            languages.add(language, new LanguageDetector.HashMap<>(N, 31));
            languagesList.add(language);
        }
        LanguageDetector.HashMap<Integer> ngramMap = languages.get(language);

        int k = n;
        for(int j = 0; j<=text.length()-n; j++){
            String ngram = text.substring(j, k);
            if(ngramMap.get(ngram) != null){
                int ngramPlus = ngramMap.get(ngram) + 1;
                ngramMap.add(ngram, ngramPlus);
            } else{
                ngramMap.add(ngram, 1);
            }
            k+=1;
        }    
        
        //ngramMap.printHashMap();
    }

    public int getCount(String ngram, String language){
        if(languages.get(language) == null || languages.get(language).get(ngram) == null){
            return 0;
        }
        return languages.get(language).get(ngram);
    }

    //the hashMap returned from apply method can be inserted here to get the language as a string
    public String checkLanguage(LanguageDetector.HashMap<Integer> result){
        String finalLanguage;
        int currentCount = 0;
        int maxCount = 0;
        ArrayList<String> languageWinners = new ArrayList<>();

        //look for languages with most votes (and store in languageWinners)
        for(int i = 0; i < languagesList.size(); i++){
            currentCount = result.get(languagesList.get(i));
                
            if(currentCount>maxCount){
                maxCount = currentCount;
                //currentCount = 0;
                languageWinners.clear();
                languageWinners.add(languagesList.get(i));
            }
            else if(currentCount==maxCount){
                languageWinners.add(languagesList.get(i));
            }
        }

        //System.out.println(languageWinners);

        //there is one language with most votes
        if(languageWinners.size() == 1){
            finalLanguage = languageWinners.get(0);
            return finalLanguage;
        }

        //multiple languages have same votes --> lexiographically sorted.
        for(int i = 0; i<languageWinners.size();i++){          
            for (int j = i + 1; j < languageWinners.size(); j++) {
                if (languageWinners.get(i).compareToIgnoreCase(languageWinners.get(j)) > 0) {
                    String temp = languageWinners.get(i);
                    languageWinners.set(i, languageWinners.get(j));
                    languageWinners.set(j, temp);
                }
            }            
        }
        finalLanguage = languageWinners.get(0);
        return finalLanguage;
    }
    
    // open a file, read its lines, return them as an array.
    private static String read(String filename) {
        // !!! NO NEED TO CHANGE !!!
                
        try {
            
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                
            Reader in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename),
                            "UTF-8");

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in);
                
            String s;
            while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Ignoriere Leerzeilen und Kommentare
            if (s.length() != 0 && s.charAt(0) != '#') {
                sb.append(s);
            }
            }
                
            reader.close();
                
            return sb.toString();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {       
            String msg = "I/O-Fehler bei " + filename + "\n" + e.getMessage();
            throw new RuntimeException(msg);        
        }
    } 

    //creating own hashmap class
    public static class HashMap<T> {

        //creating Entry class
        public class Entry {
            String key;
            T value;
            Entry next;
                
            Entry(String key, T value) {
                this.key = key;
                this.value = value;
            }
        }

        Entry[] table;
        int basis;

        public HashMap(int N, int basis) {
            table = (Entry[]) Array.newInstance(Entry[].class.getComponentType(), N);
            this.basis = basis;
        }     

        //add method, uses individual hashCode & probe function, for finding best possible index.
        public boolean add(String key, T value) {
            int index = hashCode(key);
            Entry entryOnIndex = table[index];

            if(entryOnIndex == null){
                table[index] = new Entry(key, value);
                return true;
            }
            if (entryOnIndex != null && entryOnIndex.key.equals(key)) {
                entryOnIndex.value = value;
            } 
            else{
                // Schlüssel in der HashMap suchen
                int currentIndex = index;
                int m = 0;

                while (table[currentIndex] != null && m <= table.length) {
                    currentIndex = sondieren(currentIndex, m);
                    Entry currentEntry = table[currentIndex];

                    if (currentEntry != null && currentEntry.key.equals(key)) {
                        currentEntry.value = value;
                        return true;
                    }

                    m++;
                }

                if(table[currentIndex] == null){
                    Entry newEntry = new Entry(key, value);
                    table[currentIndex] = newEntry;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        //very similar to add method. ..> possible alternative: implement a third methode to outsource redundant code. --> return the found index
        public T get(String key) {
            int index = hashCode(key);
            Entry entryOnIndex = table[index];

            if(entryOnIndex == null){
                return null;
            }
            if (entryOnIndex != null && entryOnIndex.key.equals(key)) {
                return entryOnIndex.value;
            }
            else{
                // Schlüssel in der HashMap suchen, da sondierung angewandt wurde
                int currentIndex = index;
                int m = 0;

                while (table[currentIndex] != null && m <= table.length) {
                    currentIndex = sondieren(currentIndex, m);
                    Entry currentEntry = table[currentIndex];

                    if (currentEntry != null && currentEntry.key.equals(key)) {
                        return currentEntry.value;
                    }

                    m++;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        //returns the fillratio relative to the HashMap Capacity
        public double fillRatio() {
            double ratio = 0;
            for(Entry e : table){
                if(e!=null){
                    ratio+=1;
                }
            }
            return ratio/table.length;
        }
                
        //hash-function for hashing the key (simplyfied): h(k) = (k₁ * B^(n-1) + k₂ * B^(n-2) + ... + kₙ₋₁ * B + kₙ) % N
        public int hashCode(String k) {
            double hash = 0;
            int n = k.length();

            for(int i = 0; i<k.length(); i++){
                hash = hash + (k.charAt(i) * Math.pow(basis,n-(i+1)) );
                hash %= table.length; 
            }
            
            //System.out.println("Hash-Code for " + k + ": "+ hash);
            return (int) hash;
        }

        //probe function: g(m + 1) = (g(m) + 2m + 1) % N
        public int sondieren(int index, int m) {
            return (index + 2 * m + 1) % table.length;
        }
        
        //for testing purposes only
        public void printHashMap() {
            System.out.println();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.table.length; i++) {
                Entry entry = (Entry) this.table[i];
                System.out.print(i + ": ");
                while (entry != null) {
                    System.out.print("(" + entry.key + " = " + entry.value + ") ");
                    entry = entry.next;
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    //end of HashMap Class
    }

    //reads txt files into Strings. These are used to learn languages .> given senctences are checked and the language is displayed (accuraccy is also displayed) [using different n-Gram and hashMap sizes]
    public static LanguageDetector runTest(String BASE, int n, int N) {
        
        LanguageDetector myDetector = new LanguageDetector(n, N);

        String alice_en = read("src\\alice\\alice.en.txt");
        String alice_de = read("src\\alice\\alice.de.txt");
        String alice_eo = read("src\\alice\\alice.eo.txt");
        String alice_fi = read("src\\alice\\alice.fi.txt");
        String alice_fr = read("src\\alice\\alice.fr.txt");
        String alice_it = read("src\\alice\\alice.it.txt");

        myDetector.learnLanguage("english", alice_en);
        myDetector.learnLanguage("german", alice_de);
        myDetector.learnLanguage("esperanto", alice_eo);
        myDetector.learnLanguage("finnish", alice_fi);
        myDetector.learnLanguage("french", alice_fr);
        myDetector.learnLanguage("italian", alice_it);

        
        String[] sentences = new String[] {

            // 11 x English
            "I'm going to make him an offer he can't refuse.",
            "Toto, I've got a feeling we're not in Kansas anymore.",
            "May the Force be with you.",
            "If you build it, he will come.",
            "I'll have what she's having.",
            "A martini. Shaken, not stirred.",
            "Some people can’t believe in themselves until someone else believes in them first.",
            "I feel the need - the need for speed!",
            "Carpe diem. Seize the day, boys. Make your lives extraordinary.",
            "Nobody puts Baby in a corner.",
            "I'm king of the world!",

            // 11 x Deutsch
            "Aber von jetzt an steht ihr alle in meinem Buch der coolen Leute.",
            "Wäre, wäre, Fahradkette",
            "Sehe ich aus wie jemand, der einen Plan hat?",
            "Erwartet mein Kommen, beim ersten Licht des fünften Tages.",
            "Du bist terminiert!",
            "Ich hab eine Wassermelone getragen.",
            "Einigen wir uns auf Unentschieden!",
            "Du wartest auf einen Zug, ein Zug der dich weit weg bringen wird.",
            "Ich bin doch nur ein Mädchen, das vor einem Jungen steht, und ihn bittet, es zu lieben.",
            "Ich genoss seine Leber mit ein paar Fava-Bohnen, dazu einen ausgezeichneten Chianti.",
            "Dumm ist der, der Dummes tut.",

            // 9 x Esperanto
            "Al du sinjoroj samtempe oni servi ne povas.",
            "Al la fiŝo ne instruu naĝarton.",
            "Fiŝo pli granda malgrandan englutas.",
            "Kia patrino, tia filino.",
            "La manĝota fiŝo estas ankoraŭ en la rivero.",
            "Ne kotas besto en sia nesto.",
            "Ne singardema kokino fidas je vulpo.",
            "Por sperto kaj lerno ne sufiĉas eterno.",
            "Unu hako kverkon ne faligas.",

            // 8 x Finnisch
            "Hei, hauska tavata.",
            "Olen kotoisin Suomesta.",
            "Yksi harrastuksistani on lukeminen.",
            "Nautin musiikin kuuntelusta.",
            "Juhannusperinteisiin kuuluu juhannussauna tuoreiden saunavihtojen kera, sekä pulahtaminen järveen.",
            "Aamu on iltaa viisaampi.",
            "Työ tekijäänsä neuvoo.",
            "Niin metsä vastaa, kuin sinne huudetaan.",

            // 9 x Französisch
            "Franchement, ma chère, c’est le cadet de mes soucis.",
            "À tes beaux yeux.",
            "Si j’aurais su, j’aurais pas v’nu!",
            "Merci la gueuse. Tu es un laideron mais tu es bien bonne.",
            "Vous croyez qu’ils oseraient venir ici?",
            "La barbe ne fait pas le philosophe.",
            "Inutile de discuter.",
            "Paris ne s’est pas fait en un jour!",
            "Quand on a pas ce que l’on aime, il faut aimer ce que l’on a.",

            // 9 x Italienisch
            "Azzurro, il pomeriggio è troppo azzurro e lungo per me",
            "Con te, cos lontano e diverso Con te, amico che credevo perso ",
            "è restare vicini come bambini la felicità",
            "Buongiorno, Principessa!",
            "Ho Ucciso Napoleone.",
            "L’amore vince sempre.",
            "La semplicità è l’ultima sofisticazione.",
            "Una cena senza vino e come un giorno senza sole.",
            "Se non hai mai pianto, i tuoi occhi non possono essere belli."
        };

        String[] labels = new String[] {

            "english","english","english","english","english","english","english","english","english","english","english",
            "german","german","german","german","german","german","german","german","german","german","german",
            "esperanto","esperanto","esperanto","esperanto","esperanto","esperanto","esperanto","esperanto","esperanto",
            "finnish","finnish","finnish","finnish","finnish","finnish","finnish","finnish",
            "french","french","french","french","french","french","french","french","french",
            "italian","italian","italian","italian","italian","italian","italian","italian","italian"

        };

        assert sentences.length == labels.length;

        LanguageDetector.HashMap<Integer> result = new LanguageDetector.HashMap(N, 31);
        int countCorrectDetection = 0;
        int loopCount = 0;
        double successRate = 0;

        //detect language and count how many languages were checked and how many were correct
        for(int i = 0; i<57; i++){
            result = myDetector.apply(sentences[i]);
            String detectedLanguage = myDetector.checkLanguage(result);
            //System.out.println("detected language *"+detectedLanguage+"* for: \n" + sentences[i]+"\n");
            //result.printHashMap();
            //System.out.println();
            if(detectedLanguage.equals(labels[i])){
                countCorrectDetection += 1;
            }
            loopCount += 1;
        }

        //calculate percentage
        if(countCorrectDetection != 0 && loopCount != 0){
            successRate = (double) countCorrectDetection / loopCount;
            DecimalFormat prozentFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0.00%");
            // Wandle die Double-Zahl in eine Prozentzahl mit zwei Nachkommastellen um
            String succesRateP = prozentFormat.format(successRate);
            
            System.out.println("For n = "+n+", N = "+N);
            System.out.println(loopCount + " senctences were checked. For "+countCorrectDetection+" senctences the correct language was detected.\nsucces-rate: "+succesRateP+"\n");
        }
    
        return myDetector;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runTest("31", 1, 120001);
        runTest("31", 2, 120001);
        runTest("31", 2, 120001);
        runTest("31", 3, 120001);
        runTest("31", 4, 120001);
        runTest("31", 6, 120001);
        runTest("31", 5, 120001);
        runTest("31", 7, 120001);
        runTest("31", 8, 120001);
        runTest("31", 9, 120001);

        runTest("31", 1, 1200001);
        runTest("31", 2, 1200001);
        runTest("31", 2, 1200001);
        runTest("31", 3, 1200001);
        runTest("31", 4, 1200001);
        runTest("31", 5, 1200001);
        runTest("31", 6, 1200001);
        runTest("31", 7, 1200001);
        runTest("31", 8, 1200001);
        runTest("31", 9, 1200001);
    
    }
/*
 N = 120001

 hier tabelle erstellen...
 */

    /*
For n= 1, N= 120001
57 senctences were checked. For 11 senctences the correct language was detected.
succes-rate: 19.298245614035086%

For n= 2, N= 120001
57 senctences were checked. For 11 senctences the correct language was detected.
succes-rate: 19.298245614035086%

For n= 2, N= 120001
57 senctences were checked. For 11 senctences the correct language was detected.
succes-rate: 19.298245614035086%

For n= 3, N= 120001
57 senctences were checked. For 12 senctences the correct language was detected.
succes-rate: 21.052631578947366%

For n= 4, N= 120001
57 senctences were checked. For 38 senctences the correct language was detected.
succes-rate: 66.66666666666666%

For n= 5, N= 120001
57 senctences were checked. For 56 senctences the correct language was detected.
succes-rate: 98.24561403508771%

For n= 7, N= 120001
57 senctences were checked. For 56 senctences the correct language was detected.
succes-rate: 98.24561403508771%

For n= 8, N= 120001
57 senctences were checked. For 53 senctences the correct language was detected.
succes-rate: 92.98245614035088%

For n= 9, N= 120001
57 senctences were checked. For 46 senctences the correct language was detected.
succes-rate: 80.7017543859649%

For n= 1, N= 1200001
57 senctences were checked. For 11 senctences the correct language was detected.
succes-rate: 19.298245614035086%

For n= 2, N= 1200001
57 senctences were checked. For 11 senctences the correct language was detected.
succes-rate: 19.298245614035086%

For n= 2, N= 1200001
57 senctences were checked. For 11 senctences the correct language was detected.
succes-rate: 19.298245614035086%

For n= 3, N= 1200001
57 senctences were checked. For 12 senctences the correct language was detected.
succes-rate: 21.052631578947366%

For n= 4, N= 1200001
57 senctences were checked. For 38 senctences the correct language was detected.
succes-rate: 66.66666666666666%

For n= 5, N= 1200001
57 senctences were checked. For 56 senctences the correct language was detected.
succes-rate: 98.24561403508771%

For n= 7, N= 1200001
57 senctences were checked. For 56 senctences the correct language was detected.
succes-rate: 98.24561403508771%

For n= 8, N= 1200001
57 senctences were checked. For 53 senctences the correct language was detected.
succes-rate: 92.98245614035088%

For n= 9, N= 1200001
57 senctences were checked. For 46 senctences the correct language was detected.
succes-rate: 80.7017543859649%
     */
}
```

I hope this clarifys my issue and makes it more understandable. I just couldnt figure out the correct initialization for my HashMap.

Sorry for the unstructured code, i hope it´s not a pain for anyone intersted in reading it.

Comment: This is awful code. Especially if a novice, you should be creating classes that *use* a HashMap, but are not *themselves* a HashMap, and that have methods to support their functionality. Consider using an enum for the language, unless the languages truely are unbounded. Consider changing school/teacher if they require you to write code like this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).